# Finding un-pushed commits on current branch through a function

Tags: git

I've seen a lot of great posts regarding displaying "unpushed" file commits. I've sort of constructed a function to perform - getting the list of unpushed commits on the current branch.

What I have in my .gitconfig is:

`notpushed = "!f() { git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | git diff --stat --cached origin/$1; }; f"`

Apparently, it's the `$1` that is wrong. I am simply trying to do an "automatic" selection of the current branch.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping is not the right tool in this situation. Try :

```
notpushed = "!f() { branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git diff --stat --cached origin/$branch; }; f"
```

---

There is actually a shortcut to "the upstream of the current branch" : `@{u}`

You can change your alias to :

```
notpushed = diff --stat --cached @{u}
```